# Updating objects previously created through Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, updates

I've searched high and low for an answer to this question, but it doesn't seem to be possible. Which I can almost not believe :)

I am building a Facebook integration for my website, and I am creating links through the Graph API. So far, so good. However, when it came to updating stuff, I got stuck; when my content is updated, I want to somehow update the Facebook data too, but I can't figure out how to do this. There doesn't seem to be anything in the documentation about this; I can create new items, such as links and events, I can delete them programatically, but I can't update them. I've tried doing a POST against the object URL (for example, I created a link using https://graph.facebook.com//links, I got back the ID 123456 for my new link, and I then try to update it by POSTing to https://graph.facebook.com/123456). This was just a guess, and it didn't work.

Am I missing something? Doesn't Facebook like updating the objects I created through Graph API? Thanks for any insight you might provide.

Comment: Didn't find this before, but this question seems to be very similar: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8497782/how-to-edit-an-existing-event-using-the-facebook-graph-api. As I also need to do events, I'll see how that goes, maybe this is a problem exclusive to links (and there basically isn't anything to change for links, in Facebook's judgement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was on the right track; POSTing to the object itself is the right way to go (the question I linked to in my comment was a big help). I was simply having issues storing the original ID, which meant I was POSTing to an entirely different ID. The lack of documentation from Facebook throws you off and stops you from digging deeper.